# How to access css style .advanced-pie-legend .legend-items-container .legend-items .legend-item?

Tags: css, angular, google-chrome, developer-tools, ngx-charts

I have in my google chrome

[image: ![this style]

I want to access this code in my project to modify overflow but I don't know-how.

I tried something like this :

```
.advanced-pie-legend .legend-items-container .legend-items {
  overflow: initial !important;
}
```

but didn't work.

Comment: display: inherit property didn't reflected on browser console ?

Comment: no. It didn't reflect